# Numpy problems (python doesn't run anything)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I had some trouble with another package so I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python with brew (I have MacOS). I think I must have done something wrong because now whenever I try to run or import anything in Python I get the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from . import numeric   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 3093, in <module>
    from . import fromnumeric   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _methods   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 158, in <module>
    _NDARRAY_ARRAY_FUNCTION = mu.ndarray.__array_function__ AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__' '
```

I was wondering if anyone has any idea of what is wrong. It puzzles me because I tried importing `pandas`, `NLTK`, or even `Numpy` and the error is the same. Is it a dependency thing?

Comment: How do you proceed to get this error? E.g. do you get it from IDLE?

Comment: I tried Idle, python from the terminal and also Jupyter notebook!

Comment: What did you do finally?

Comment: Nothing suggested was working so I completely uninstalled python 3.7 and 2.7 and all the folders, packages, hidden folders etc., and reinstalled everything.

Answer (score 0):

This must happen because you have Python 2 and 3 and some version conflict is had with numpy. Uninstalling numpy for both versions and reinstalling will fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

What about being more explicit. Open your OS shell prompt and force the installation of your library as well as of its dependencies, by doing

```
pip3.7 install pandas --force-reinstall # will imply the reinstallation of numpy
```

For testing purpose, open your [IDLE Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/idle.html), now `import pandas` should work.

Comment: hey! already tried that and it doesn't work :) The last of a string of error is the following:

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy-1.16.0.dist-info/RECORD'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: @Paschalis Have you closed all the processes that are using python?

Comment: @Paschalis or do `pip3.7 install pandas --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir`